# Pyspark label rows based on time window and double condition match

Tags: python, sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

The idea is to identify users who bought an `item` offline (`no` in the `online` column) and tried to buy the same item online (`yes` in the `online` column) in the last 7 days.

This means that for each `no` in the `online` column I need to search through the `yes` values 7 days prior, which also match the `user_ID` and `item` values of the `no` instance and then label matches as `1` and non-matches as `0`.

Sample dataset (notes on the right):

```
+-------+----+------+--------------+
|user_ID|item|online|      datetime|
+-------+----+------+--------------+
|      1|  66|   yes| 02-10-21 9:30|
|      1|  24|   yes| 02-10-21 9:30|
|      1|  66|    no| 06-10-21 9:30| # <- 1 ('user_ID' and 'item' matched in the last 7 days)
|      2|  24|    no| 03-10-21 8:01| # <- 0 ('user_ID' didnt match in the last 7 days)
|      2|  24|   yes| 03-10-21 8:02|
|      2|  24|    no| 03-10-21 8:03| # <- 1 ('user_ID' and 'item' matched in the last 7 days)
|      3|  31|   yes| 05-10-21 8:32|
|      3|  66|   yes|10-10-21 10:57|
|      3|  66|    no|14-10-21 12:07| # <- 1 ('user_ID' and 'item' matched in the last 7 days)
|      3|  31|    no|15-10-21 12:07| # <- 0 ('item' didnt match in the last 7 days)
+-------+----+------+--------------+
```

Resulting dataset:

```
+-------+----+------+--------------+------+
|user_ID|item|online|      datetime|result|
+-------+----+------+--------------+------+
|      1|  66|    no| 06-10-21 9:30|     1|
|      2|  24|    no| 03-10-21 8:01|     0|
|      2|  24|    no| 03-10-21 8:03|     1|
|      3|  66|    no|14-10-21 12:07|     1|
|      3|  31|    no|15-10-21 12:07|     0|
+-------+----+------+--------------+------+
```

Can't figure this one out. Is there a way of doing this with a windowed function? I'm working with spark and a large dataset (>10 mln records).

Any pyspark or sql magicians that could help?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rangeBetween` window function to look up last 7 days.

First cast `datetime` to long value to be able to used with `rangeBetween`.

```py
# If the datetime is string
df = df.withColumn('datetime', F.to_timestamp(df.datetime, 'dd-MM-yy H:mm'))
df = df.withColumn('long_dt', df.datetime.cast(LongType()))

# If the datetime is timestamp type
df = df.withColumn('long_dt', df.datetime.cast(LongType()))
```

Then create window function to look up past 7 days with for the same `user_ID` and `item`.

```py
w = (Window.partitionBy(['user_ID', 'item'])
    .orderBy('long_dt')
    .rangeBetween(-7*24*60*60, -1)) # -7 days to -1 second before.
```

Use this window function to count the row and if you see for the second time (> 0), you want to return 1. You also want to return only when `online == no`, so add the filter at the end.

Edit: Thanks to @blackbishop, I updated the counting logic.

```py
df = (df.withColumn('result', (F.count(F.when(df.online == 'yes', 1)).over(w) > 0).cast(IntegerType()))
     .filter(df.online == 'no'))
```

Result

```
+-------+----+------+-------------------+------+
|user_id|item|online|           datetime|result|
+-------+----+------+-------------------+------+
|      1|  66|    no|2021-10-06 09:30:00|     1|
|      3|  31|    no|2021-10-15 12:07:00|     0|
|      3|  66|    no|2021-10-14 12:07:00|     1|
|      2|  24|    no|2021-10-03 08:01:00|     0|
|      2|  24|    no|2021-10-03 08:03:00|     1|
+-------+----+------+-------------------+------+
```

Comment: Works like a charm! The solution doesn't look that complicated but I lacked the knowledge on window functions to get it. Now that I see how useful they can be, I definitely have to pick up some courses for those. All the more reason to thank you so much for your help @blackbishop and @emma!

Answer (score 1):

Other answers demonstrated how to use window functions. Here's a another way using `left_semi` join, which returns only users who bought items offline after they tried to bought the same items online 7 days earlier:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

# cast string into timestamp if not already done
df = df.withColumn('datetime', F.to_timestamp("datetime", 'dd-MM-yy H:mm'))

df_on = df.filter("online = 'yes'").alias("on")
df_off = df.filter("online = 'no'").alias("off")

result = df_off.join(
    df_on, [
        F.col("on.user_ID") == F.col("off.user_ID"),
        F.col("on.item") == F.col("off.item"),
        F.col("on.datetime") >= F.expr("off.datetime - interval 7 day"),
        F.col("on.datetime") < F.col("off.datetime")
    ],
    "left_semi"
)

result.show()
#+-------+----+------+-------------------+
#|user_ID|item|online|           datetime|
#+-------+----+------+-------------------+
#|      1|  66|    no|2021-10-06 09:30:00|
#|      2|  24|    no|2021-10-03 08:03:00|
#|      3|  66|    no|2021-10-14 12:07:00|
#+-------+----+------+-------------------+
```

Note if you want the users who bought item offline but haven't tried to bought it online before (corresponding to `result=0`, replace semi join with `left_anti` in the above query.

Answer (score 0):

I've included the pandas code to easily build out a sample dataframe.  The spark code starts after that.

It's based upon groupby and shifting the online and datetime values. The idea being that the previous value to a `no` for any given id/item needs to be within 7 days to count.

```
import pandas as pd

from pyspark.sql.functions import lag, col, datediff, when
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

df = pd.DataFrame({'user_ID':[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3],
                  'item':[66,24,66,24,24,24,31,66,66,31],
                   'online':['yes','yes','no','no','yes','no','yes','yes','no','no'],
                  'datetime':['02-10-21 9:30',
'02-10-21 9:30',
'06-10-21 9:30',
'03-10-21 8:01',
'03-10-21 8:02',
'03-10-21 8:03',
'05-10-21 8:32',
'10-10-21 10:57',
'14-10-21 12:07',
'15-10-21 12:07']})


df['datetime']  = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'], dayfirst=True)


df = spark.createDataFrame(df)


df = df.withColumn('o_shift', lag(df['online']).over(Window.partitionBy('user_ID','item').orderBy('datetime')))
df = df.withColumn('d_shift', lag(df['datetime']).over(Window.partitionBy('user_ID','item').orderBy('datetime')))
df = df.dropna()

df = df.withColumn('t_delta', datediff(col('datetime'),col('d_shift')))


df = df.withColumn('result',when(
  (col('online')=='no') &
  (col('o_shift')=='yes') & 
  (col('t_delta')<=7),1
).otherwise(0))

df.sort('user_id','datetime').select('user_id','item','online','datetime','result').show()
```

Output

```
+-------+----+------+-------------------+------+
|user_id|item|online|           datetime|result|
+-------+----+------+-------------------+------+
|      1|  66|    no|2021-10-06 09:30:00|     1|
|      2|  24|   yes|2021-10-03 08:02:00|     0|
|      2|  24|    no|2021-10-03 08:03:00|     1|
|      3|  66|    no|2021-10-14 12:07:00|     1|
|      3|  31|    no|2021-10-15 12:07:00|     0|
+-------+----+------+-------------------+------+
```